Error: "Precondition check failed" when using Firebase App Distribution to distribute AAB
I'm trying to distribute an Android App Bundle (AAB) using Firebase App Distribution with the following command built with flutter:
firebase appdistribution:distribute build/app/outputs/bundle/stagingRelease/app-staging-release.aab --app <PROJECT_ID> --groups internal --debug

However, I encounter the following error:
[2024-06-09T21:27:37.700Z] Object "" in "firebase.json" has unknown property: {"additionalProperty":"flutter"}
[2024-06-09T21:27:37.703Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2024-06-09T21:27:37.704Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2024-06-09T21:27:37.706Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/apps/<APP_ID>/aabInfo [none]
[2024-06-09T21:27:38.472Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/apps/<APP_ID>/aabInfo 400
[2024-06-09T21:27:38.472Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/apps/<APP_ID>/aabInfo {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Precondition check failed.","status":"FAILED_PRECONDITION"}}

Error: failed to determine AAB info. HTTP Error: 400, Precondition check failed.

Is it a problem with my firebase.json configuration, Firebase Console configuration, or Flutter/Android build configuration?
I have flutter flavor
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I would like the aab to upload :)

It says that your PROJECT_ID doesn't match or your project doesn't exist.
